# Call to DeviceCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync() never returns

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, maui

To be able to call Microsoft.Graph API on my .Net MAUI app, I need to get an access token. I followed this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3

And here is my code:

```
internal class GraphHelper
{
    private static string[] _graphUserScopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    // User auth token credential
    private static DeviceCodeCredential? _deviceCodeCredential;
    // Client configured with user authentication
    private static GraphServiceClient? _userClient;

    public static void InitializeGraphForUserAuth(Func<DeviceCodeInfo, CancellationToken, Task> deviceCodePrompt)
    {
        string adTenantId = "MY TENANT ID";
        string adClientId = "MY CLIENT ID";

        _deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(deviceCodePrompt,
            adTenantId, adClientId);

        _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(_deviceCodeCredential, _graphUserScopes);
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetUserTokenAsync()
    {
        // Ensure credential isn't null
        _ = _deviceCodeCredential ??
            throw new NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for user auth");

        // Ensure scopes isn't null
        _ = _graphUserScopes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Argument 'scopes' cannot be null");

        // Request token with given scopes
        TokenRequestContext context = new TokenRequestContext(_graphUserScopes);
        AccessToken response = default;

        try
        {
            response = await _deviceCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return response.Token;
    }
}
```

Call to await _deviceCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(context) never comes back. And only in about 10 minutes the following exception is thrown:

Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: DeviceCodeCredential authentication failed: Verification code expired before contacting the server

I would like to know how I can diagnose and/or fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call to await ... never comes back.

`await` that never returns is a **deadlock**.

To find out where the problem starts, and fix it:

- Put a breakpoint at start of `GetUserTokenAsync`.
- Look at call stack. Check each method in call stack to see if it is declared `async` (you'll have to go to source code of each method).
- What is the first method you encounter that is NOT declared `async`?
- Look at the `async` method it calls: is there an `await` in front of that call? If not, that is your problem.

**Starting a chain of `async/await` calls from a non-async context can cause a thread deadlock.**
Typically happens on UI thread. Most common mistake is attempting to call inside a `constructor`.

IF it is the problem I describe, try adding `await`.

- Build. If no compile error, it should now work.
- If there **is** compile error at that `await`, a fix is to **create an async context** to do the `await` in.

To await on UI thread (MainThread):

```cs
// An alternative is "MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread".
Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
{
  ... = await ...;
  // Code after your await line goes here.
}
// DO NOT have any code here, unless it is okay to run it BEFORE the dispatched await finishes.
```

To await on a background thread:

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
... same logic as above ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But all the methods in the call stack are async...

Comment: I also noticed this in the Output: "Skipped 535 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread". Placing the call in Task.Run() does not help...

Comment: DId you do `Task.Run( **async** () => **await** ... );`?  Do all those `async` methods use `await` when they call the next method on the call stack?

Comment: Yes, they all use await, and here is the call:

                return
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    AccessToken response = await _deviceCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(context);
                    return response.Token;
                });

Comment: That should work. (Should avoid deadlock; I don't know if there is some other authentication issue that would result in never returning.) Sorry, I am out of ideas.